# Rough Idle Only When in Drive with AC On

Tags: ford, ac, rough-idle, idle, escape

I have a 2010 Ford Escape and for a few years I've noticed that when the AC is on, the car idles very rough when in drive. If it's in park or neutral and the AC is running it's as smooth as silk. Driving it with the AC on I don't notice the shaking, but when I'm waiting at a red light for example, it can get annoying.

I've told the dealer about this in the past who seems to think that this is normal/acceptable, but I'd like to get rid of this issue. The car has near 90K miles on it and aside from this issue, is great. Anything I should be looking at or recommending they check? The AC itself runs fine and is very cold. Also, the RPMs seem steady when this happens.

Comment: Have the throttle body cleaned thoroughly and reset the idle strategies, have this done by a competent repair shop.

Comment: What maintenance actions have you done? It very likely just needs some general overall love'n.

Comment: @kyle_engineer Nothing other than regular maintenance

Comment: Have you ever had a proper AC service (evacuation, vacuum and regas+new compressor oil) done by a shop? Have you got any engine cooling issues?

Comment: @Al_ Nope to both. The AC and defroster run fine, and the engine temp hasn't been an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a weak motor mount. I would start there first. But fyi, Ford's do seem to have a vibration with a.c. on and in drive. But should be a minimal vibration if at all.